# In the bible, who saw the light and was blinded?

Tags: bible, identify-this

I heard a quote somewhere that described a biblical character who "saw the light" and was "blinded" and "crawled" his way through a certain location.

Who is this referring to?

Comment: Please [edit] this to tell us which phrases you have already searched for, and which verses aren't what you're looking for. [Verse search questions which don't do this are off-topic](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4199/6071).

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, you are thinking of Saul (who later went by the name "Paul"):

> As [Saul] neared Damascus on his journey, suddenly a light from heaven flashed around him. He fell to the ground and heard a voice say to him, “Saul, Saul, why do you persecute me?”
>
> “Who are you, Lord?” Saul asked.
>
> “I am Jesus, whom you are persecuting,” he replied. “Now get up and go into the city, and you will be told what you must do.”
>
> The men traveling with Saul stood there speechless; they heard the sound but did not see anyone. Saul got up from the ground, but when he opened his eyes he could see nothing. So they led him by the hand into Damascus. For three days he was blind, and did not eat or drink anything.
>
> <sub>—[Acts 9:3-9 (NIV)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts%209%3A3-9&version=NIV)</sub>

The only difference is that Saul/Paul did not crawl to his destination, but rather was led there by his companions because he was blinded.